# mod_rewrite redirect from any page to home page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect if someone goes to any folder e.g. `http://site.com/images/` or `http://site.com/images` to `http://site.com`. 
Unless he goes to file e.g. `http://site.com/images/index.php` in this case it does not redirect

now i use

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ [R=301,L]
```

but i think its not perfect because e.g. if someone comes on http://www.site.com it does not work.

Keep in mind due to server configuration i need to put .htaccess in every folder.

Comment: I assume that this .htaccess file is in your /images/ directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is the *-f* flag:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

**If you are only looking at stopping someone from getting a list of the files** you have in the folder, you may want to consider instead adding:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will tell apache not to display a directory list if no index page is present in the given directory.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

The last thing to note, if you are not familiar with how .htaccess works, apache scans the current folder and any of its parent folders - **you should be okay with only adding a single .htaccess file in your web root** for http://site.com. This has been covered in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713343/htaccess-or-httpd-conf).

Comment: `'-f' (is regular file)
Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.`
...
`You can prefix the pattern string with a '!' character (exclamation mark) to specify a non-matching pattern.`

Comment: It just does not work for me to add single .htaccess i think its in server configuration